# What is Windows Update Error 0x80d03805?

Tags: windows-update

I came across an error on Windows Update.  The error is `0x80d03805`.  I looked it up on the [Windows Update error code list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/938205/windows-update-error-code-list), but didn't find what I was looking for.

I also [searched it on the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=Windows+Update+Error+0x80d03805&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), but all I can see is [errors on the Microsoft/Windows store](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store-winpc/cant-download-apps-in-the-store-error-0x80d03805/22ac177a-5dd8-494a-9ff9-9a4bc8b1579e).

[image: Screenshot of Windows Update with the error 0x80d03805]

<sup>**Click to enlarge.**  Screenshot of Windows Update with the error `0x80d03805`.</sup>

Comment: This isn’t extremely odd, 1803 hasn’t been officially released, are you running an Insider Preview build?

Comment: I'm not running an Insider Preview build, but I signed up for Windows Insider.  Windows 10 v1803 is now released, and you can get the update via Windows Update or the Media Creation Tool.

Comment: 17334 only exists in the Release Preview channel. Have you actually downloaded with the Media Tool?  I see absolutely no news articles to support it’s actually been released.

Comment: Microsoft hasn’t submitted a blog post on it, and as of yesterday, the release still had not happen[.](https://www.windowscentral.com/april-update-may-be-final-name-windows-10-redstone-4?amp)

Comment: [Windows 10 April Update will start rolling out on May 8 according to leak](https://www.neowin.net/news/windows-10-april-update-will-start-rolling-out-on-may-8-according-to-leak)